# How can I run the same Python program (script) on multiple servers (or machines)?

Tags: python, server, concurrency, bots, telegram

How can I run the same Python program (script) on multiple servers (or machines)? I programming a telegram bot (using python-telegram-bot API) and I wish my program running on multiple servers at the same time.

How can do it? without get something like **"telegram.error.Conflict: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"**

This bot will be used for concurrency porpuse (like checking graphical administrative information).

Thanks a lot for the help (and suggestions).

```py
def main() -> None:
    global updater
    global dispatcher
    
    updater = Updater(token="here should be the bot token provided by BotFather", use_context=True, workers=999)    
    
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start, 
                                    run_async=True)

    choice_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, 
                                    choice, run_async=True)

    income_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.regex(DECLARATION), 
                                    income, run_async=True)

    end_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.regex('Fin') | Filters.regex('Done') | Filters.regex(FINISH), 
                                    end, run_async=True)    
    
    stmt_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.regex(STMT) & ~Filters.command,
                                  declaracion_por_dia, run_async=True)

    stmt2_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.regex(STMT2) & ~Filters.command, 
                                   calendario_ultimos_siete, run_async=True)

    return_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.regex(RETURN) & ~Filters.command,
                                    choice, run_async=True)     

    callbackquery_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(declaracion_por_rango, run_async=True)

    cancel_convhandler = CommandHandler('cancel', cancel, 
                                            filters=Filters.regex('Cancel') 
                                            | Filters.regex('CANCEL'), run_async=True)

    conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(
                                                entry_points=[start_handler],   
                                                states={
                                                        CHOICE: [choice_handler, end_handler],                                                     
                                                        INCOME: [income_handler, end_handler],                                                     
                                                        CHOOSE: [stmt_handler, stmt2_handler, return_handler],
                                                        DEC_BY_RANGE: [callbackquery_handler]
                                                       },
                                                fallbacks=[cancel_convhandler],
                                                run_async=True
                                            )

    dispatcher.add_handler(conversation_handler)
    # dispatcher.add_error_handler(stmt_handler, run_async=True)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: I was tempted to edit the title of your question, but I won't because I don't know Telegram. But, how does this question have anything to do with Python? It _seems_ as if your question should be, "How can I run multiple instances of the same Telegram bot?" It seems as if you might have the same problem no mater what language you used to program the bot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solomon Slow. The telegram bot is programmed in python, using Telegram API (python-telegram-bot)... and yes, How can I run multiple instances of the same Telegram bot?